# Spring Boot - 504 gateway timeout

Tags: timeout, gateway

I just created simple Spring starter project that contains a single controller and only one Rest API that print logs on the console. I don't see any exceptions/errors in the spring boot server startup, everything looks fine. but I get 504 Gateway timeout error when I access the rest API through Postman or Curl. here is my controller class.

**Controller Class**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController 

@RequestMapping(path = "/test")

public class SampleController {

    private static final Logger LOG = 
     LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleController.class.getSimpleName());

    @GetMapping(value = "/method")
    public void saveEcu() {

        LOG.info("---> reached test/method----> ");

    }

}
```

**Log console**

```
2018-06-28 22:03:52.890  INFO 7040 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-06-28 22:03:52.898 DEBUG 7040 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding PropertySource 'Management Server' with lowest search precedence
2018-06-28 22:03:52.901  INFO 7040 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-06-28 22:03:53.014 DEBUG 7040 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Looking for resource handler mappings
2018-06-28 22:03:53.014 DEBUG 7040 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Found resource handler mapping: URL pattern="/**/favicon.ico", locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], class path resource []], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@3c744059]
2018-06-28 22:03:53.014 DEBUG 7040 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Found resource handler mapping: URL pattern="/webjars/**", locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/webjars/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@ab2dd851]
2018-06-28 22:03:53.015 DEBUG 7040 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Found resource handler mapping: URL pattern="/**", locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@c804fffb]
2018-06-28 22:03:53.042  INFO 7040 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9091 (http)
2018-06-28 22:03:53.043 DEBUG 7040 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding PropertySource 'server.ports' with highest search precedence
2018-06-28 22:03:53.047  INFO 7040 --- [           main] c.e.demo.NewStarterProjectApplication    : Started NewStarterProjectApplication in 3.822 seconds (JVM running for 5.088)
```